# How to show iPhone5-Splashscreen with PhoneGap V1.x

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova, iphone-5

Is there a way to hack PhoneGap 1.0 to make it show the correct splashscreen on iPhone5 to avoid the white flash of the webview?

I can controll the splashscreen with

```
if(navigator.splashscreen) navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

but on iPhone5 it is showing the wrong image. I need to show the Default-568h@2x.png image.
I know in PG2 this is fixed but I want to avoid updating the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured out how to fix this issue in older Phonegap, and it's a pretty easy fix. In PhoneGapDelegate.m, find this:

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"]];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[image release];
```

and replace with this:

```
UIImage* image;

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
{
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default-568h@2x" ofType:@"png"]];
}
else
{
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"]];
}
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[image release];
```

For some reason, you need to specify full image name for iPhone 5 image just like in the code above. If you specify it with just @"Default-568h", image won't be loaded at all.

Comment: Can't find this code snippet nor the file inside the project.

Comment: The file should be inside PhoneGapLib/Classes folder. PhoneGapLib is wherever you installed PhoneGap by default. On Mac I think that's Documents folder. You can just search for PhoneGapLib in Spotlight and it will show where it is.